# CSS menu is not working properly if i place my Image slide show

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just tired to fix it that is when i place my Image Slide show then footer menu is not working properly. But if i remove **a javascript code** then Image Slide Show is not working.

**A javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0
/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Total Javascript code for the page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0
/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--if i remove this code then footer menu is working-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.eislideshow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#ei-slider').eislideshow({
                animation           : 'center',
                autoplay            : true,
                slideshow_interval  : 3000,
                titlesFactor        : 0
            });
        });
    </script>
<script src="js/mootools.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/tabslide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**My site link:**
    http://creativeartbd.com/BCSA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're usng both mootools and jquery, they both use '$'.  So you'll need to use jquery noconflict.  Change your code to something along these line:

```
    <script src="js/mootools.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/tabslide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0
/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--if i remove this code then footer menu is working-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.eislideshow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

        $j( document ).ready(function() {
            $j('#ei-slider').eislideshow({
                animation           : 'center',
                autoplay            : true,
                slideshow_interval  : 3000,
                titlesFactor        : 0
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Well, It's working fine but pls check my site link when i refresh the page then for few second the menu is pop up. why ?

Comment: did you see that problem ?

Comment: Yes, I see it. I don't know anything about that slider control, but you may have to start the sub menus as 'display: none'.  Also, I updated my answer because your code didn't wrap the eislideshow in a document ready call and it should be.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Barbara Laird.